# Why doesn't Barak change every time Garion is in trouble?

Tags: the-belgariad

In the Belgariad, Barak's 'Doom' is that he turns into a bear everytime Garion is in danger.  Be it boar or duel with a god.  However, there are moments where Garion's in extreme danger and he doesn't change such as when the group is in the Woods of the Dryads and are attacked by the mud things.  Is there any rhyme or reason to the shape changing, or did the author simply forget in that moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garion is not actually in any peril in that situation, nor is anyone else, although they didn't realise that right at the moment.

> Salmissra certainly wanted to get their attention, but the purpose of the mud-men and the snakes inside them was to deliver a message, not to actually threaten Garion or any of the others. Nobody, the reader included, realises that until everything's over and done with, but nothing in what the snake says to Polgara implies that it or its companions were supposed to actually hurt anyone.

Most of the other times when Barak doesn't change are similar: either Garion is actually in a position to do something about things himself, or he is otherwise protected--for example...

> ...when Silk is fighting Brill on the parapet of Rak Cthol, Garion is initially seemingly in danger, but in practise, he really isn't. Silk is right there, and the contest between Light and Dark is between Silk and Brill. Garion is just a spectator.

Comment: Hmm, guess I didn't see it like that. It's more intention than actual danger. But does he change during the conflict later with Chamdar?

Comment: He doesn't. There, too, Garion is not in danger. Chamdar is the catalyst that wakes Garion up. From the point of view of the Prophecies, that was Chamdar's only real purpose in his entire long life -- to be the one Garion hates enough to slap and set fire to, which is what makes Garion conscious of his own power and opens up everything else he's supposed to do. If Garion had failed, **then** he would have been in peril, but the entire prophecy would also have fallen apart!